# Getting Brent price from Yahoo Finance

Tags: yql

I try to get actual Brent price from Yahoo Finance via YQL, but I can't fing it in
yahoo.finance.quote or yahoo.finance.quotes tables. May be I should use other table or special quote name? Does anybody know?

Comment: yahoo finance api has been closed

Answer (score -1):

According to [this site](https://uclue.com/?xq=7567) you won't find the Brent Crude price on Yahoo Finance.

There is [this source of data on the price](https://ycharts.com/indicators/brent_crude_oil_spot_price) which has API access, and also [the code CLX15.NYM](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=clx15.nym) on Yahoo! Finance which tracks crude oil prices but not Brent specifically.

Comment: How about BZJ16.NYM ?